# Optimize stored procedure with a LIKE comparison

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have this question. I could see some issues with `like`.

Could you guys have a look at this query and help me optimize it? I really appreciate your taking the time and supporting me here.

```
  UPDATE F_State
  SET StateName = L.State_Name
  FROM Reg.Location L 
  JOIN F_State S ON CONVERT(nvarchar, L.stateID) = s.StateCode  --BECAUSE THIS IS NVARCHAR and ststeid isnt
  WHERE S.StateName LIKE '%)%' 
    AND L.ZIPCODE = S.ZIPCODE 
    AND L.CITY=S.CITY
```

I have around 300,000 rows to update....this is not helping at all. Could you guys help me resolve it?Thanks again guys!

Comment: Using `LIKE '%....%'` basically prevents SQL Server from being able to use any indexes. If you really need this - there's not a whole lot you can do about the runtime - you just need patience.....

Comment: @marc_s....Hey now its almost half an hour and still running...??Thanks again guys..

Answer (score 0):

If you were on oracle you could use function based index with INSTR(insted LIKE '%)'), that would solve your problem.

But in your case LIKE '%..%' issue is not relevant.

1. You are doing update on whole table, is that really necessary?
2. Do you really have to JOIN F_State again?
3. Do you have index(or unique constraint) on StateCode and index on ZipCode?

I can't see, what are you doing, but I guess you are trying to set F_State.StateName when it contains '%)%' with Location.State_name. Appropriete location is found having stateID the same as StateCode in F_State (wtf, really? one is nonvarchar ID and one is varchar... but okey) nad the same ZipCode and the same City.

```
UPDATE F_State S
   SET S.StateName = (SELECT State_Name 
                      FROM Reg.Location L 
                      WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar, L.stateID) = s.StateCode 
                        AND L.ZipCode = S.ZipCode 
                        AND L.City = S.City 
                      LIMIT 1)
 WHERE S.StateName LIKE '%)%';
```